# Filter List Using Predicate Of Another List

Tags: c#, list, linq, filter

Looking to filter a list using the values from another list. I've seen many threads based on this, but they're mostly all filtering one list based on if the value exists in the second list.

My scenario is I have 2 lists that are parallel, so index 0 of list A corresponds to the property of some 0th object which also has another property stored in list B at index 0, and so on for higher indices. I need to filter list A, based on the value of list B at the same index. I could do it with a for loop as shown below, but wondering if there is a more elegant solution using linq filters.

Example code:

```
List<string> A = //some list of strings
List<string> B = //another list of strings, the same length as A
List<string> res = new List<string>(); //new list to collected the filtered result

for (int i = 0; i < A.Count; i++)
   if (B[i] == someVal)
       res.Add(A[i]);
```

I'm hoping to have something along the lines of (fake code):

```
List<string> res = A.Where(x => B[indexOf(x)] = someVal);
```

I know A.Select((x, i) => ...) can be used to get the index, but I'm not sure how I can correlate that back to the values of A.

Comment: Do you just need `List<string> res = A.Zip(B, (a, b) => (a, b)).Where(x => x.a == x.b).Select(x => x.a).ToList();` or (in 6.0) `List<string> C = A.Zip(B).Where(x => x.First == x.Second).Select(x => x.First).ToList();`?

Comment: Please stop putting tags in titles. That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly after found my solution. Where also has an overload to include the index.

Solution is:

```
List<string> A = //some list of strings
List<string> B = //another list of strings, the same length as A
List<string> res = A.Where((x, i) => B[i] == someVal);
```

Comment: FYI, `=` is an assignment

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Enumerable.Zip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0). Using this overload you `Zip()` will return a tuple of the elements at the same index in both arrays for all indices.

```cs
var array1 = new[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var array2 = new[]{ 1, 2, 999, 4, 5 };
var filtered = Enumerable.Zip(array1, array2)
                         .Where(x => x.First == x.Second)
                         .Select(x => x.First);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", filtered));
```

Expected output:

```
1, 2, 4, 5
```